# requirement of mc56f8367 header files

Tags: c, embedded, codewarrior

i am new to embedded programming i like to program a bldc motor with mc56f8367 with IDE

CodeWarrior® Development Studio for 56800/E Digital Signal Controllers (Classic IDE) v8.3
but i m unable to find header files for the particular microcontroller and i am using a 64 bit windows 7 os and there some progress to be taken for the perfect functioning of codewarrior, is there any other version that support 64 bit Windows 7, containing header files or any other way to download header files

Comment: Haven't used your particular MCU, but on the classic versions you should typically find all libraries under something along the lines of C:\Program...\Codewarrior for ... \(MCU name)\lib  and \src respectively. Under project settings, you should have target->access paths with these two lib and src paths pointed out.

Comment: Possibly update your toolchain?  The [NXP page](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/additional-processors-and-mcus/digital-signal-controllers/digital-signal-controllers:56F836X-816X) for the part has a tool download link for classic Codewarrior 10.6 with an update, and for Codewarrior for Eclipse 11.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check for updates on that IDE, maybe the device was introduced later. (e.g. "CodeWarrior for MCUs" which got an update to 11.1 last year)
- Check, if NXP provides some examples or extra libs
- Check for a more generic header, maybe it has some device specific extensions, depending on some compiler switches (incl the target switch) enabling this code part.
- You should be able to write such a header or register definitions yourself. It's not so much rocket science but rather tedious work of reading the processor manual and writing the header definitions.

Comment: The OP claims to be using classic Codewarrior. If it was the Eclipse version then it is perfectly normal that it can't find its own libraries, it is broken per design - the CW version of it in particular.